# What Elasticsearch DSL is needed to create a compound AND-OR query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I must apologise if this is rather trivial, but I am quite new to the Elasticsearch (8.5) world and struggling a bit to find a suitable solution from the documentation.

Ultimately, the goal is to create a DSL that represents:

```
(attr1 IS NOT NULL AND attr2 IS NULL) 
  OR (attr3 IS NOT NULL AND attr4 IS NULL) 
  OR attr5 = true
```

I started down the scoring path but cannot get consistent results.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below DSL query:

Here, I put all the 3 `OR` condition into `should` clause and all the inner `AND` condition into `bool` clause.

`exists` query inside `must` for checking not null value and `exists` query inside `must_not` for checking null value.

Please note that `exists` query with `must_not` will work only if you dont have field in document or field is set as null. it will not work if field is having empty string value.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "attr1"
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "attr2"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "attr3"
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "attr4"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "attr5": {
              "value": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing that. It worked. However I ended up using the Elasticsearch translate API to give me the DSL I need.

Comment: Great to hear that its worked.